# How can textures with transparent spots be correctly applied to multiple stacked plane instances in threejs?

Tags: three.js

I'm creating 512 instances of the same 1x1 plane with a texture that has transparent areas. The planes are randomly spread around the origin like the image below.

How can the planes in front be drawn after the planes behind so that the transparency of the planes in front take into account the output of the planes from behind?

(with depthTest disabled)
[image: scene problem]
(with depthTest normal)
[image: scene problem, variation 1]

For reference, the transparency disabled version of the instanced geometry. This proves that the planes are correctly positioned.

[image: no transparency for position proof]

Update:

Adding code as asked:

```
import {


Mesh,
  ShaderMaterial,
  Vector3,
  PlaneBufferGeometry,
  EdgesGeometry,
  LineBasicMaterial,
  LineSegments,
  InstancedBufferAttribute,
  UniformsLib,
  BufferAttribute,
  TextureLoader,
  InstancedBufferGeometry,
  DoubleSide,
} from 'three'

import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

import {
  randomValueBetween,
} from '../../utils'

const vertexShader = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/vertex.glsl'), 'utf8')
const fragmentShader = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/fragment.glsl'), 'utf8')

const createInstancedAtrributes = (geometry, instanceCount) => {
  const startseed = new InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instanceCount * 1), 1)
  const scale = new InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instanceCount * 3), 3)
  const offset = new InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instanceCount * 2), 2)
  const orientationY = new InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instanceCount), 1)
  const baseScale = 0.5

  for (let i = 0; i < instanceCount; i += 1) {
    scale.setXYZ(i,
      baseScale * randomValueBetween(0.8, 1.3, 1),
      baseScale * randomValueBetween(0.8, 1.3, 1),
      baseScale * randomValueBetween(0.8, 1.3, 1),
    )

    orientationY.setX(i, randomValueBetween(0.0, 1.0, 3))
    startseed.setX(i, randomValueBetween(1, 3, 1))
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < instanceCount / 4; i += 4) {
    const randomX = randomValueBetween(-3.5, 3.5, 1)
    const randomY = randomValueBetween(-3.5, 3.5, 1)
    offset.setXY(i, randomX, randomY)
  }

  geometry.addAttribute('scale', scale)
  geometry.addAttribute('offset', offset)
  geometry.addAttribute('startseed', offset)
  geometry.addAttribute('orientationY', offset)

  return { scale, offset }
}

const createInstancedGeometry = (instancePerUnitCount) => {
  const geometry = new InstancedBufferGeometry()
  geometry.maxInstancedCount = instancePerUnitCount

  const shape = new PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1, 3)

  const data = shape.attributes

  geometry.addAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(data.position.array), 3))
  geometry.addAttribute('uv', new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(data.uv.array), 2))
  geometry.addAttribute('normal', new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(data.normal.array), 3))
  geometry.setIndex(new BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array(shape.index.array), 1))
  shape.dispose()

  createInstancedAtrributes(geometry, instancePerUnitCount)

  return geometry
}

export default class GrassDeform extends Mesh {
  constructor() {
    const geometry = createInstancedGeometry(8 * 256)

    const uniforms = {
      uTime: {
        type: 'f',
        value: 0,
      },
      uMap: {
        type: 't',
        value: null,
      },
    }

    const textureLoader = new TextureLoader()
    textureLoader.load(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/grass-texture-01.png'), (t) => {
      uniforms.uMap.value = t
    })

    const material = new ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: Object.assign({},
        UniformsLib.ambient,
        UniformsLib.lights,
        uniforms,
      ),
      vertexShader,
      fragmentShader,
      lights: true,
      transparent: true,
      side: DoubleSide,
    })


    super(geometry, material)

    this.geometry = geometry
    this.material = material
    this.up = new Vector3(0, 0, 1)

    const lineGeo = new EdgesGeometry(geometry) // or WireframeGeometry
    const mat = new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 })
    const wireframe = new LineSegments(lineGeo, mat)
    this.add(wireframe)

    this.frustumCulled = false
  }

  update({ ellapsedTime }) {
    this.material.uniforms.uTime.value = ellapsedTime
  }
}
```

And the object is added to the scene like this:

```
const grass2 = new GrassDeform2()
grass2.position.set(-1, 0, 0.50)
grass2.rotateX(Math.PI / 2)
scene.add(grass2)
dirLight.target = grass2


const animate = (ellapsedTime = 0) => {
  stats.begin()
  grass2.update({ ellapsedTime })
  /// other scene stuff
  renderer.render(scene, playerController.camera)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

The vertex shader:

```
#if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0
struct DirectionalLight {
  vec3 direction;
  vec3 color;
  int shadow;
  float shadowBias;
  float shadowRadius;
  vec2 shadowMapSize;
};
uniform DirectionalLight directionalLights[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];
#endif

uniform float uTime;

attribute vec2 offset;
attribute vec3 scale;
attribute float startseed;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vDirectionalLightDirection;
varying vec3 vDirectionalLightColor;
varying vec3 uNormal;

void main() {
  vec3 pos = position * scale;

  pos.x += offset.x;
  pos.z += offset.y;
  pos.y += (scale.y - 1.0) * 0.5;

  pos.y = orientationY

  vPosition = pos;
  uNormal = normal;


  vUv = uv;
  uNormal = normal;
  vDirectionalLightDirection = directionalLights[0].direction;
  vDirectionalLightColor = directionalLights[0].color;


  float variation = startseed + uTime * 0.002;
  float pass = (0.5 + pos.y) * 0.05;

  pos.x += sin(pass + variation) * pass;
  pos.z += cos(pass + variation + 0.01) * pass;
  pos.y += sin(pass + variation - 0.01) * pass;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos,1.0);
}
```

And the fragment shader (has some extra stuff for light, not added for now):

```
uniform sampler2D uMap;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vDirectionalLightDirection;
varying vec3 vDirectionalLightColor;
varying vec3 uNormal;

void main() {
  vec4 map = texture2D(uMap, vUv);

  vec3 lightVector = normalize((vDirectionalLightDirection) - vPosition);
  float dotNL = dot( uNormal, lightVector );

  vec3 baseColor = map.rgb;

  vec3 lightedColor = vDirectionalLightColor * 0.6 * dotNL;

  if ( map.a < 0.5 ) discard; //!!! THIS WAS THE LINE NEEDED TO SOLVE THE ISSUE

  gl_FragColor = vec4( map.rgb , 1 );
}
```

After applying the change from the final result, the scene looks right!

[image: working version]

Comment: I will provide an answer, but please add your code to the question.

Comment: updated question with code and final result after applying your change!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your problem with alpha testing. Use a pattern like the following in your fragment shader:

```
vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );

if ( texelColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;
```

Your material will no longer need to have `transparent = true`, since you appear to be using a cut-out in which the texture alpha is either 0 or 1.

three.js r.88

Comment: I am amazed by the amount of things I learn everyday about shaders. Thanks! It worked!

Comment: Did you understand what I said about the `material.transparent` property?

Comment: Yep, I'm not using transparent true anymore on my material. Transparent should be used for semi transparent things.